# Would new type2 transactions be prioritised over legacy type0 transactions?

Tags: uniswap, fees, eip-1559

regarding ethereum eip 1559 upgrade, i see it still supports type0 legacy transactions. Is there any benefit for using new type2 transactions except for reducing fees if i just want fast uniswap transactions?